# Don't fadeIn, until fadeOut is fully completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, function, fade

I have it so when I click on a button, and old box fades out and the new box fades in.

I don't want the .fadeIn() to take place until the .fadeOut() has finished. This way there will never be a time where two containers are shown at the same time.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

To do this, simply use the [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) callback:

```
$('#thing').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('#otherThing').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Sorry for that small edit. OCD is killing me today...

Comment: @NULL I can't even tell what you edited! But thanks for whatever it was :)

Comment: If you press `edited just now` you can see the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally try:

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    $("#thing1").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#thing2").delay(1000);
    $("#thing1").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

I have done many similar effects in jQuery and I am 95% sure this will work.